# How to customize javafx scrollbar thumb thickness by css?

Tags: css, javafx, scrollbar

I tried to set thickness by `-fx-pref-height: 10px;` when orientation is horizontal, and by `-fx-pref-width: 10px;` when scrollbar orientation is vertical. But is doesn't work.

```
.scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: derive(black, 90%);
    -fx-background-insets: 2, 0, 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0em;
    -fx-pref-height: 10px;
}

.scroll-bar:vertical .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: derive(black, 90%);
    -fx-background-insets: 2, 0, 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0em;
    -fx-pref-width: 10px;
}
```

How to achieve this by customizing css?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can set the padding of the scrollbars to shrink the thumbs' thickness.

```
.scroll-bar:vertical {
    -fx-pref-width: 16.5;
    -fx-padding: 3;
}

.scroll-bar:horizontal {
    -fx-pref-height: 16.5;
    -fx-padding: 3;
}

.scroll-bar, .scroll-bar:pressed, .scroll-bar:focused {
    -fx-font-size: 15;
}
```

Comment: Logical. Why 16.5?

Comment: you can test any values you like. i edited my answer and added the answer of @anlar. arrows size are bound with the font size.

Answer (score 4):

Scrollbar width is configured via it's font size, eg:

```
.scroll-bar {
    -fx-font-size: 100px;
}
```

[image: scrollbar]

Comment: Are you sure that css is actually applied to your scene? I've tried to create simple project and that style is affecting all scrollbars as in image above.

Comment: Yes, I applied css to the scene. But is not working.

Comment: I need to customize scrollbar thumb.

Answer (score 3):

Set the padding in arrow of scroll-bar by below css.

```
.scroll-bar .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-padding:2.25;
 }
.scroll-bar .increment-arrow {
    -fx-padding:2.25;
}
```

[image]